# Could you remove extra bangs from my swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

Could you suggest how to clean up this abomination

```
func restartLastSession(let extra : String?)
{
    let rescopes  = NSMutableArray(array: [ "restart" ])
    if(extra != nil && !(extra?.isEmpty)!) {
        rescopes.addObject(extra!)
    }
```

that transformed into

```
func restartLastSession(let extra_ : String?)
{
    let rescopes  = NSMutableArray(array: [ "restart" ])
    if let extra = extra_ where !extra.isEmpty {
        rescopes.addObject(extra)
    }
```

thanks to Eric D who did not allow me to wing reading the optionals chapter of the swift book
I suppose this is resolved with no provisions to contribute +10 to Eric's karma ;-)

Comment: "Optionals" chapter is all you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Answer (score 1):

Simplify by dropping unnecessary keywords (such as `let`), and by using true Swift arrays.

```
func restartLastSession(extra: String?) {
  var rescopes = ["restart"]   
  if extra?.characters.count > 0 { rescopes.append(extra!) }

  // do something else with rescopes before returning, else it will be discarded
}
```